# How did SIFE earn the question asking account ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

https://stackoverflow.com/users/556553/sife is currently blocked from asking questions, according to those who closed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87944/how-long-is-take-until-unblock-my-account. But based on muggle-visible statistics, he's apparently asked only 6 questions, and made 66 answers. It's possible he's deleted a truckload of bad questions, but it doesn't seem likely.

Did he earn the question asking account ban, or is it possible his IP is shared with someone dodgy?

Comment: Why doesn't it seem likely?

Comment: @Bobby: I play werewolf. I know what is or isn't suspicious behaviour! (More pragmatically, mmyers says only one question has been deleted).

Comment: Oh damn I suck at that game (though it's fun)...I always get hung or shot in the first three days. :( But I see what you mean and I also see mmyers comment now.

Comment: Man! One taste---just one hit---of the ♦ super powers and you jonesing for them on every other site in the network! I wanna go and look, and it isn't working!

Comment: As for the now deleted question: I was one to vote for closing it. It only said *"I can't a ask question in Stack Overflow, after I making some seach I found I am temporary blocked, so how long this block take."* However, seeing that their SO profile did have more than 1 reputation and did not show some warning, one could be sure it was (and is) indeed the dreaded "no longer accepting questions" ban, not some temporary suspension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is currently able to ask questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005923/captured-packets-of-edonky2000-protocol)) - either he was blocked from asking questions and it was over-turned (unlikely) or he and half of meta mistakenly thought he was blocked from asking questions, even though that was never the case (more likely).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe he is just misunderstanding that he cannot ask because [his recent questions were closed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556553/sife#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_newest-ansort_newest)

**Edit**: But if he had many posts like the following, fretje's answer might be correct (deleted post count towards those bans).

[image]

Comment: But then a question asking ban won't stop one from abusing answers like that... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, that would lead to account suspension, isn't it :-)

Comment: @fretje, sorry for not typing your name correctly!

Comment: Nine deleted answers (all at 0 score except one -1), and one deleted question. [Here's the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550400/simple-socket-library-need-some-check-closed) but I'm not going to link to all the answers.

Comment: If deleted answers are taken into account, then I *assume/hope* such is only done when there's already a low quality score for the questions. Otherwise new users who just saw the same answer being posted [while they were typing it too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), should not be deleting their late answers anymore... But: I have a lot of faith in the developers.

Answer (score 4):

In cases with users that are close to the edge, I recommend exercising your right to vote on their questions. Either up or down.

Comment: If what mmyers says is correct and a full representation of the situation, he isn't even close to the edge.

Comment: Why now my question is deleted?

Comment: @SIFE, your first question was answered in [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this), which is still there. So, your first question did not have any value here. You should already have read that FAQ, but given your new (also closed) question maybe you did not? Anyway: this very question and that FAQ are all there is to say about it.

Comment: Based on currently available information, this answer doesn't seem to be correct for this particular situation.

Comment: @andrew it was correct at the time it was written, and it is actually still correct.

Comment: @Jeff: You must have known with your super diamond powers that he didn't have a stash of deleted bad questions!

Answer (score 3):

I'm just gonna give the stock answer here: *All his posts are taken into account, this also includes his deleted posts.* Why don't you think he (or the system) has deleted a lot of his posts?

I'm not 100% sure on this point, but I think his deleted *answers* are also taken into account.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm very much in favour of giving edge cases scrutiny on Meta, and having a moderator or team member confirm what happened. It's the only way for us muggles to know waht the automated process does.

Comment: @Pekka: They don't want us to know that the process does...

Comment: Why would he leave six out of hundreds of them undeleted? Just so that it didn't look suspicious?

Comment: @Andrew: Maybe he just left his best posts, or the ones he thought weren't bad...

Comment: @fretje .. and nobody is expecting them to let us know. But if a user who, from the outside, hasn't done anything wrong, and even has *answered* some questions, gets banned, the natural reaction is to ask "why?" Something that can be answered without giving away crucial details of the process

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Posts can be deleted by moderators, or by community (by spam/offensive flagging, or close+delete votes). However, the shared-IP ban is a (troubling) possibility.

Comment: @Pekka: Well, I agree with you, but all the previous similar questions like this one have been answered with a similar stock answer like the one I gave... I don't think they will all of a sudden give more details now.

Comment: @fretje yeah, and that's okay. If a mod steps up and says that there's more to it than we can see, I'm completely happy.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's such a good idea being all secret about the algorithm... Haven't we all been "beaten" with the phrase "Obscurity is not the same as security", or how does it exactly go again? ;-)

Comment: @fretje: I fail to see the need to know that. All we know is that it steps in if necessary, and so far I haven't heard of a single case in which it was wrong. Even if we would know the exact algorithm, how would that help? We'd look at his profile and start yelling `But that's wrong, he doesn't have enough questions to get a ban` and along comes a diamond mod `He has 100 deleted questions`. I fail to see how this would help.

Comment: @Bobby: Mind you, I never said anything about the algorithm being wrong. I also didn't say I *needed* to know the algorithm. I'm just stating facts here and my personal opinion about being secret about it not being the right solution.

Comment: @Bobby Even if you fully trust the team (which I, and I think most of us, do) there's nothing wrong with a bit of community oversight (ie. asking why the user was blocked) over what is an automated, algorithm-driven process. The "I haven't heard of a single case in which it was wrong" argument is invalid IMO - if a user gets their block lifted, you usually wouldn't hear about it.

Comment: @fretje I delete only one post, and I had not been blocked.

Comment: @SIFE, what do you mean with *"I had not been blocked"*?

Comment: @Arjan I mean even I delete my post, I didn't get blocked after that until to day, the post was [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686595/query-not-resulting-correct-records/5686650.

Comment: @SIFE: so you're talking about an answer of yours? You only deleted one? And you deleted no questions? If that is the case, then there might indeed be a problem with the algorithm, and we're gonna have to wait for someone from the team to confirm this.

Comment: That, @fretje, or [YOU's find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87948/how-did-sife-earn-the-question-asking-account-ban/87951#87951) (which was deleted by a moderator) is one of many more.